# How to add ID attribute to each submenu?

Tags: menus, walker, sub-menu, id

I would like to add an `ID attribute` to each list `<ul> submenu`. I am using the `Walker class` extension. I have managed to modify some elements, but I am left to solve this one problem. I need the ID attribute to expand the menu in the mobile version. Unfortunately, I don't know exactly how to do this.
The way the menu works is that I put a `button` in front of each submenu  with a `data-target attribute` that targets in the ID of that submenu.

This is what the fragment of my `functions.php` file looks like with the `Walker class extension`

```
class Walker_N_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        // Depth-dependent classes.
        $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
        $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
        $classes = array(
            'sub-menu',
            'collapse',
            'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );
        $button = ( $depth > 0 ) ? '<button class="btn-submenu" data-target="#submenu1"><ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="chevron forward outline"></ion-icon></button>' : '<button class="btn-submenu" data-target="#submenu1"><ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="chevron down outline"></ion-icon></button>';
        $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

        // Build HTML for output.
        $output .= "\n" . $indent . $button . "\n" . $indent . '<ul id="submenu1" class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

        // Depth-dependent classes.
        $depth_classes = array(
            ( $depth == 0 ? 'nav-item' : 'submenu-item' ),
            'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
        );
        $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

        // Passed classes.
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

        // Build HTML.
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

        // Link attributes.
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ' class="' . ( $depth == 0 ? 'nav-link' : '' ) . '"';

        // Build HTML output and pass through the proper filter.
        $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
            $args->before,
            $attributes,
            $args->link_before,
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
            $args->link_after,
            $args->after
        );
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Since I don't know how to do this correctly, the code generates the same ID for each submenu at this point.
Ultimately, I would like each button to have a different data-target attribute that will match each submenu ID it is over.

In addition to searching the forums for a similar topic, I tried to solve this problem using the `preg_replace` function by adding such a function to the `functions.php` file:

```
function change_submenu_id( $menu ) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $menu = preg_replace( '/<ul id="" class="sub-menu/' , '<ul id="'. $i .'" class="sub-menu' ,$menu);
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'change_submenu_id' );
```

Unfortunately, I'm doing something wrong by which this function generates the digit 0 for each ID....

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Walker_N_Menu` class's `start_lvl()` method, you're setting the `<ul>`'s `id` to `submenu1`. You can change this (using, in this example, the `$depth` parameter passed to `start_lvl()`) to be unique:

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    // Depth-dependent classes.
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array(
        'sub-menu',
        'collapse',
        'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
    );
    $button = ( $depth > 0 ) ? '<button class="btn-submenu" data-target="#submenu1-' . $depth . '"><ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="chevron forward outline"></ion-icon></button>' : '<button class="btn-submenu" data-target="#submenu1-' . $depth . '"><ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="chevron down outline"></ion-icon></button>';
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // Build HTML for output.
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . $button . "\n" . $indent . '<ul id="submenu1-' . $depth . '" class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
}
```

If you need this for more than one menu in a page, you should be able to pass in a menu prefix in the `$args` array to the `start_lvl()` method.

As to why your `add_filter()` code doesn't seem to work properly: functions hooked to filters need to `return` a value, generally speaking, and your function isn't returning anything. Also, running a `for()` loop over the values won't do what you're expecting; I would suggest that, if you *were* returning a value (ie, `return $menu;` at the end of the function), you'd find all the values would be `9`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. At the moment I have several submenus on each level with the same `id` e.g. `submenu1-1`, `submenu1-2`. I don't quite understand how to solve this.